# Check if Google Fit is already connected

Tags: android, google-fit

I need to implement a button which should enable/disable Google Fit, but I cannot find a way to check if GF is already authorized.

Something like this (app start):

```
if(GF == enabled) 
    show "Disable GF" button
else
    show "Enable GF" button
```

I don't want to check if I have rights on GF call, but on app start.
Something like settings.

```
GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions))
```

returns false always.

Comment: you got any solution on this?

Comment: Any solution for this @vanste25?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( I changed logic because of this..